# Change name application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

i have developed a software last year the version is 2013(CB2103)in WPF with Visual Studio ,now i need create from the same project the version 2014 ,it is simple just i need to change name of the file.exe (from CB2013 to CB2014) but when i change the name of the Assembly Name from CB2013 to CB2014 then deploy it and when installing appear an Error that say already there is the same version of the software installed on the computer ,sincerely we need both version installed on the computer then do you have any tips or idea how to work out this issue?

Thanks so much for your attention

Comment: Does your assembly has a strong name, and register itself into GAC when installing?

Comment: if you try to open a older project in a new version it will try to migrate and ideally this works in all cases.Is that not sufficient?

Comment: `when installing` - What tool you use for installing? Your installer might still be configured with same name and version maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a "Setup Project", then you need to generate a new GUID for the `Product Code`...so that it allows it to be installed as a distinct instance (rather than forcing you to uninstall the previously installed one, or upgrade).

Also optionally you probably want to update the attributes (AssemblyTitle, AssemblyDescription, AssemblyProduct, etc) in your AssemblyInfo.cs file, so that you name it CB2014 instead of CB2013.

[image]

[image]